# bootstrap modal sometimes not showing

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have implemented simple bootstrap modal,here is the code:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<script>
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  console.log(1);
});
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  console.log(2);
});
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
  console.log(3);
});
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  console.log(4);
});
</script>
```

Now when i click on button "Open Modal" for 10-15 times, it stops working, its not opening the modal popup.

I also checked the change in that case, so its not adding "in" class in the modal.Also I am tracking the same with js, so when modal doent comes up in that case it only shows console.log(1); but not others.

Comment: you may have other errors in your page

Comment: you are attaching same event repeatedly, so thats what you get every time a event is triggered.

Comment: @madalinivascu there is no any other error on page

Comment: @Nagaraju I didnt get your point, please can you explain more ?

Comment: sorry my mistake your binding events looked similar

Comment: try my code, i just added bootstrap.js to your code, may be this will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add js code in showing modal.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#btnOpenModal").click(function(){
     $("#myModal").modal('show');
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"  id="btnOpenModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

working fine when i add bootstrap.js to your code. try this may be this will help you

```js
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  console.log(1);
});
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
  console.log(2);
});
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
  console.log(3);
});
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  console.log(4);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```